# Interface doesn't go up with ip link set interface up

Tags: networking, arch-linux, network-interface

## EDIT

A posteriori, the problem was most likely related to the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1010309/157358).

---

## Original post

Until yesterday, Internet was just fine and I connected without much problems. I then disabled the network interface, trying to understand a little more how to manage these kind of things, issuing the command (`wlp6s0` is my wireless network interface) :

```
#ip link set wlp6s0 down
```

The interface was successfully disabled as expected.
Unfortunately, it didn't go back to an UP state since.

#### What I tried and other info:

**1)** The first thing I did was of course issuing the command

```
#ip link set wlp6s0 up
```

to bring the interface up.
Doing this, no errors are given, but the interface remains DOWN, as shown by the output of

```
$ip link show
```

Looking with `journalctl` or `dmesg` however the only given error seems to be

```
$journalctl -xe | grep tail
...
IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlp6s0: link is not ready 
...
```

***What does this error mean?***

**2)** I initially also had the [`netctl`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl) network manager. Thinking that could have been the source of the problem I uninstalled it with

```
#pacman -R netctl
```

And then proceeded to stop the `netctl` services I could find and removed them manually from

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants
```

Nothing changed.

**3)**
Following discussions on similar problems on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245434&page=2), I blacklisted the module `wmi` as explained in the link. Still no luck.

**4)**
Searching around on similar issues reveals a common problem related to some hardware clock, which can be diagnosed with `rfkill`.
This doesn't seem to be case though, as the output of `rfkill list` shows:

```
$rfkill list
0: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**5)** I also have Windows 7 on the same laptop (in dual boot). On Windows I can connect with no problems to my wireless network. So the problem isn't in the laptop hardware nor in the wireless network.

Comment: Probably you need to use `iw` to configure WiFi settings (e.g., network to connect to). Maybe something like `wpa_supplicant` to do authentication. Not sure if you can get the link to show up without that.

Comment: First thing I would check (since it has bitten me before too) is as you are having this problem on a laptop, is whether there is a physical keyboard combination (probably brand specific) for dis- and enabling wifi. It might be that the "ip link" commands and the key combination are not in sync, as in, yes, you can disable wifi from the command line, but only enable it with the key combination.

Comment: @JdeHaan do you refer to the rfkill caveat which is mentioned in the arch wiki? If yes, I don't have the rfkill program installed so I'm not sure how to follow those instructions.  Otherwise, is there a way to check if such a key combination exists from the terminal?

Comment: @glance Like I wrote, it is (hardware) brand specific. So check your keyboard for odd (off-colored) key texts or symbols. One of them might have a wifi like picture.

Comment: @JdeHaan there is no such thing that I can see. Is there no way to detect something like that from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I managed to fix it by first killing all `dhcpcd` processes:

```
killall dhcpcd
```

Then when I had a look at `ifconfig`, it said that my Wi-Fi interface is still up, so I ran:

```
ifconfig interface down
```

(replace *interface* with yours of course).

After that the Wi-Fi interface seems to be able to go up fine.

Comment: As of [2011](https://www.archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-net-tools/) on any standard archlinux install this would return `ifconfig: command not found`

Comment: @don_crissti I am running the live boot version of arch, which still seems to have the ifconfig, not too sure why.

Comment: ifconfig is deprecated https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig

Comment: @don_crissti the new version of ifconfig is `ip` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-network-interfaces-names-command/