# wlan0 down and ip link set wlan0 up doesn't work

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, iwlwifi

Running Kali linux and ax210 intel wireless card. Installed the driver .59 ucode. Getting the following dmseg....

Saw some post about deleting the file `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` in `/lib/firmware` but I don't see that file in my /lib/firmware directory. Could it be somewhere else or is that an old fix?

```
# dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    3.956693] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.968428] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
[    3.968437] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.968452] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    3.968672] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.968682] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    4.102730] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.258916] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm (-2)
[    4.328799] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: a4:6b:b6:3d:61:fc

# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope hostg
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8c:04:ba:99:7c:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.218/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 82392sec preferred_lft 82392sec
    inet6 fe80::8e04:baff:fe99:7c57/64 scope link noprefixrouteg
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:4b:92:74:8c:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr a4:6b:b6:3d:61:fc
```

I run:

```
ip link set wlan0 up
```

but it still shows as DOWN.

Anyone have any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kernel are you running?

Comment: I'm not telling that the Wireless card is working or not, but that's a normal state for a Wireless card unless it's associated for example to an Access Point. Bringing it administratively up isn't enough for Wireless. You need a tool like wpa_supplicant to handle it. Being on Kali linux, this tool might not be running by default.

Comment: `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm` is in the `firmware-iwlwifi` package on debian, I'd guess that it's probably the same package name on kali.   Try `apt install firmware-iwlwifi`.

Comment: Kernel 5.10.0-kali8-amd64.   Debian 5.10.40-1kali

Comment: @cas firmware-iwlwifi is already the newest version (20210315-2kali)

Answer (score 1):

On Kali something is needed to manage `wpa_supplicant` to use adapter (that can be network-manager or someother `wpa_supplicant` management tool).  It may have to do with the way Kali connects `ip` and `ifconfig` - they have been linked in recent versions.  Previously and usually (if `network-utilities` are installed on debian 10, then `ifconfig` and `ip` conflict, then forcing one to be disabled).

Recently I discovered the chipset of the adapter may cause problems when using IP command ([this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312541/276874) may help solve your question).

For this excercise assume `$adpt` is your adapter (substitute yours with correct `wlan0`, `wlan1`, or `wl0j3p`, etc. )

```
service network-manager stop
sudo ifconfig -a | grep wlan
```

- to confirm what ifconfig is calling wlan

```
sudo ip link set $adpt down
sudo ifconfig $adpt down
sudo ifconfig $adpt hw ether A1:11:A1:A1:A1:11
sudo ip link set $adpt address A1:11:A1:A1:A1:11
sudo macchanger -m A1:11:A1:A1:A1:11 $adpt
```

- may not be necessary in your case but it also may be needed....

```
sudo ifconfig $adpt up
sudo ifconfig -a
```

- verification step before moving forward

```
sudo service network-manager start
sudo service network-manager status | grep status
```

- another verification step (it is surprising how many places the network adapter can be lost using IP so it is useful to check it every step of the way and backtrack to beginning if something corrupts the adapter)

```
sudo nmcli c up id xyzz-wirelessnet
```

- if using network-manager if not then different connection command likely used

```
nmcli c show --active
```

Although Kali forum sometimes ignore some user questions, but historically unix.stackexchange will delete/close questions stating kali and refer user to kali forums...reddit will not close/delete but the braintrust may not be as helpful....just fyi for future reference.